# How to group data from a txt using awk?

Tags: awk, grouping

I have a set of data like:

```
firstname lastname state zipcode
 john         doe   oh   44110
jane          doe   ca   90210
john          doe2  ca   90210
jane          doe   pa   19810
```

My question is using AWK how do I display data to look like:

```
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane          doe   ca   90210
john          doe2  ca   90210
```

I want to list all persons from a particular state with a particular zip code

I have tried

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $7(state)= "California", $8(zip)= "90210"}'
```

This displays:

```
firstname lastname California 90210
 john     doe      california 90210
jane      doe      California 90210
James     doe      California 90210
```

instead of:

```
firstname lastname state zip
john     doe      California 90210
jane      doe      California 90210
James     doe      California 90210
```

Comment: The data set is actually really huge and it has like 12 different columns however I only need the 1st, 2nd, 7th and 8th columns, which are firstname, lastname, state and zip. I was using the above as an example of how the data is setup, however when I submitted what I tried, I forgot to change 7 and 8 to 3 and 4 per the example

Comment: I understand and will keep in mind for future post.  This is what I was trying to do :Display a list of people in California from us-500.csv residing in 95111 zipcode? But I was instructed to use awk to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1 || /ca/' file
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane          doe   ca   90210
john          doe2  ca   90210
```

Comment: Thank you so much and its simple.

Comment: @TrinaJMoMoore Is it simple, but if will print lines containing `ca` anywhere in the line, so If there is a first name or a last name containing ca it will also get printed, regardless of the state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==1||($3=="ca"&&$4==90210)' file
```

This prints the first line, and all other lines where the third column is "ca" and the fourth column is 90210.

Comment: This only returned the headers not the actual  persons names, state, or zipcode. I apologize I am a beginner at this or maybe I don't quite understand @user000001

Comment: If the third field is "ca" and the fourth one is "90210" the line will get printed. Check again the samples you are working with, to see that it actually matches what you have posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

zip code already includes the state information, it will be redundant to specify it.

```
$ awk -v zip="90210" 'NR==1 || $NF==zip' file
```

will give you

```
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane          doe   ca   90210
john          doe2  ca   90210
```

I think you want to change display from state code to state name as well

```
$ awk -v zip="90210" 'NR==1 || $NF==zip {sub(/ca/,"California",$3);print} ' file
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane doe California 90210
john doe2 California 90210
```

However, spacing is broken now.  You have to change output file separator to tab.

```
$ awk -v zip="90210" -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1 || $NF==zip {sub(/ca/,"California",$3);print} ' states
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane    doe     California      90210
john    doe2    California      90210
```

Almost there, except the first line. You have to force `awk` to replace field separators

```
$ awk -v zip="90210" -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{$1=$1;print;next} $NF==zip {sub(/ca/,"California",$3);print} ' states
firstname       lastname        state   zipcode
jane    doe     California      90210
john    doe2    California      90210
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify state if you're specifying zip and that solves your problem of trying to map "California" to "ca". Just do:

```
$ awk -v zip="90210" '(NR==1) || ($4==zip)' file
firstname lastname state zipcode
jane          doe   ca   90210
john          doe2  ca   90210
```